# Object rooted by IMsoComponentManager.FPUshMessageLoop()

Tags: c#, winforms, debugging, memory-leaks

I am debugging a problem where I have a memory leak. At a point in code that I know that my object should have been disposed and de-referenced, I have explored the memory profile with sos. It turns out that I have a root from 
Application+ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPUshMessageLoop()

And as shown from sos:

```
010ced70 6edcee21 System.Windows.Forms.Application+ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr, Int32,     Int32)
    ebx:  (interior)
        ->  03ff3330 System.Object[]
        ->  0300cbf0 System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[[System.Object, mscorlib]]
        ->  1929b008 System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1+Slot[[System.Object, mscorlib]][]
        ->  18f3d384 OurCompany.Components.ApplicationWorkflow.WorkflowBase+CallbackTransaction
```

Does anyone know what this is?

Also, this seems to be happening on a computer with Windows 8 (.net 4.5), but not from a machine running Windows 7 (.net 4.0). This last piece of information is not solid.

Comment: This just looks like Workflow plumbing.  Which object is yours?

Comment: I forgot about WF. WorkflowBase+CallbackTransaction is ours. We are using Winforms as you can see, but we are not using WF. We have our own component called ApplicationWorkflow. It has existed long before MS WF.